# Git to TFS 2008 one way migration (with history)

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm a newbie to Git. I'm exploring one-way one-time migration of Git repository to TFS (with history). I'm looking into plugin [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). I couldn't find any help/wiki/blog on this particular scenario. Can I use git-tfs checkin or git-tfs clone command in this case? Any examples would be great!! Thank you!!

Comment: Does this help? http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/15/git-tfs-where-have-you-been-all-my-life/

Comment: Thanks KMoraz for the link! It didn't cover TFS push part.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft just released cross platform plug-in: git-tf. Please see video here - http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VisualStudio/Announcing-git-tf-Combining-the-local-repository-of-Git-with-the-integrated-ALM-of-TFS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it on test repository. Big thanks to Ivan Danilov. Here are exact steps:

> 1. [Download zip](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases)
> 2. Unblock (right click file->properties->unblock) downloaded files (win 7 for me)
> 3. Copy to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
> 4. Now you should be able to run Git tfs commands.
> 5. Create empty TFS target folder (assuming you are migrating to empty folder)
> 6. Bind TFS to Git repository and then upload Git changes to TFS. 
>      (Run commands in sequence):

```
   git tfs init http://server:8080/tfs/collection $/project -d 
   git tfs pull
   git rebase tfs/default
   git tfs rcheckin
```

Please note rebase is the key. It could be more complicated if you have branches etc and I haven't tried those scenarios.

Please see this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/git-tfs-dev/browse_thread/thread/929d005ff9cdcc23) and this [link](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/91) for more details.

[image: Git]
[image: TFS]

Comment: This looks as if it doesn't preserve history - or if it does you have to do a new git tfs rcheckin for each changeset from git. Is this correct? Also, how well does it handle renames and deletes?

Comment: I did rcheckin only once after rebase. I haven't tried but I see multiple open issues on renames here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues

Comment: I get out of memory issues when trying to rebase a large repository - has anyone encountered similar issues?