# How to migrate from BITBUCKET to Tfs version control?

Tags: version-control

After significant search and no inputs I am forced to ask this question here.
Is there a simple set of steps to follow to migrate from GIT/bitbucket to TFS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Git to TFS with all history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757043/migrate-git-to-tfs-with-all-history)

Comment: When you have migrated to TFS, do you want to continue to use Git for source control or do you want to use TFVC (TFS's centralized source control tool)?

Comment: No, I do not want to use Git any longer. TFS should become the single source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone your repo from Bitbucket to a local folder.
2. Install [git-tf](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf) tool.
3. Create TFVC repository in your TFS project.
4. Use below commands to check-in the files and histories in TFS TFVC repo:

   `cd /path/to/local/git/repo`

   `git tf configure http://yourserver:8080/tfs/Collection “$\TeamProjectName” –force`

   *(I’m using the flag “force” to ensure that the configuration is being applied)*

   `git tf checkin –deep –autosquash –keep-author`

Now you got a TFVC repo like your Git repo :)